# Integrating my Java app with moodle

Tags: java, php, mysql, moodle

I have a java based application that manipulates a mysql database. I would like to integrate this particular application with an installation of moodle. Kindly let me know the procedure. I am kind ah confident with java and php as individual entities. But the question is how to integrate both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simlpest efficient approach would be run a socketserver in the java code and send requests from PHP using a client socket (e.g. [pjb](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) implements most of the heavy lifting for you) . Alternatively you could expose the Java via a container as an HTTP service (e.g. using SOAP or REST) and call that from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

[Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) supports both PHP and Java:

> Thrift is a software framework for scalable cross-language services development. It combines a software stack with a code generation engine to build services that work efficiently and seamlessly between C++, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl, Haskell, C#, Cocoa, JavaScript, Node.js, Smalltalk, and OCaml.